# Exclude "Uncategorized" post comments in Recent Comments Widget (sidebar) in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget

I would like to exclude Uncategorized post comments in my wordpress' sidebar widgets. I think it will be done in the functions.php. but any method will do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have posts in that category you can switch default category trough dashboard.

Settings > Writing , edit Default Post Category.

or try to add this to functions.php:

```
function remove_uncategorized_category( $categories ){

    foreach ( $categories as $cat_key => $category ){
        if( $category->term_id == 1 ){
            unset( $categories[ $cat_key ] );
        }
    }

    return $categories;

}
add_filter('get_the_categories', 'remove_uncategorized_category', 1);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, what I'm trying to do is to NOT display the post comments base on the category "Uncategorized", I don't want to unset or remove my posts. Thanks!

Comment: Oh im sorry about that. The best way to fix that is to find code of widget query and add this: $query->set( 'category__not_in' , array( 1 ) );